# Makefile in C - no rule to make target

Tags: c, makefile

I'm trying to make a Makefile, even tough I can do a simple Makefile, I can't get it working when I need to sort the files in different folders, what I need is /translator folder with: Makefile, src folder with all .c and .h files, files folder with the files to translate, and bin folder for all .o files and the executable.

This is the makefile I made:

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -Wall -Werror -Wextra -pedantic -std=c99 -g 
OBJECTS = word.o pair.o list.o dict.o set.o

translate : $(OBJECTS)
    mkdir ./files
    mkdir ./bin
    cd ./src; $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o translate $(OBJECTS) main.c; mv *.o ../bin; mv translate ../bin

word.o: word.c word.h
    cd ./src; $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c word.c -o word.o

pair.o: pair.c pair.h word.h
    cd ./src; $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c pair.c -o pair.o

list.o: list.c list.h word.h pair.h
    cd ./src; $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c list.c -o list.o

dict.o: dict.c dict.h word.h list.h
    cd ./src; $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c dict.c -o dict.o

set.o: set.c set.h word.h list.h
    cd ./src; $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c set.c -o set.o

.PHONY : clean

clean  :
    $(RM) ./bin/*.*
    rmdir ./bin
```

But as soon as I type `make` the terminal shows:

```
make: *** No rule to make target `word.c', needed by `word.o'.  Stop.
```

I previously made a Makefile for Java this way and it worked, and there is, for sure, a file word.h and word.c inside the src folder, so why is it not finding it?

Comment: I did that in Java, now I read that the correct way is to do && so that you know the cd command was succesfull

Comment: Even after removing cd ./src it still doesn't find the target files to make word.o, I assume I'm standing in the wrong folder but how should it be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You told make that `translate` (in the current directory) depends on `word.o` etc. (in the current directory), which depends on `word.c` and `word.h` (in the current directory).

> there is, for sure, a file word.h and word.c inside the src folder, so why is it not finding it?

Because you didn't tell it to look in `src`.

You could do something like:

```
OBJECTS = word.o pair.o list.o dict.o set.o main.o
# main.o is also an object file

bin/translate: $(addprefix bin/,$(OBJECTS))
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $+ -o $@

bin/word.o: src/word.c src/word.h
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

# ... repeat for all source files
```

(See also https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/File-Name-Functions.html and https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html.)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your actions don't match your dependencies -- you have a rule that says it builds `word.o` from `word.c`, but then the command with it actually produces `src/word.o` from `src/word.c`.  Lookking at other rules, you don't even really want `src/word.o`, you want `bin/word.o`.

So you need to fix all of your rules to have the correct names and paths for the files that you actually want to use:

```
OBJECTS = bin/word.o bin/pair.o bin/list.o bin/dict.o bin/set.o

bin/translate : $(OBJECTS)
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $(OBJECTS) src/main.c
bin/word.o: src/word.c src/word.h
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
bin/pair.o: src/pair.c src/pair.h src/word.h
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
bin/list.o: src/list.c src/list.h src/word.h src/pair.h
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
bin/dict.o: src/dict.c src/dict.h src/word.h src/list.h
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
bin/set.o: src/set.c src/set.h src/word.h src/list.h
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
```

Once you do that, you see that most of the actions are the same, so you can use a pattern rule and dependencies:

```
OBJECTS = bin/word.o bin/pair.o bin/list.o bin/dict.o bin/set.o

bin/translate : $(OBJECTS) src/main.c
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $(OBJECTS) src/main.c
bin/%.o: src/%.c
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
bin/word.o: src/word.h
bin/pair.o: src/pair.h src/word.h
bin/list.o: src/list.h src/word.h src/pair.h
bin/dict.o: src/dict.h src/word.h src/list.h
bin/set.o: src/set.h src/word.h src/list.h
```